# How to return the count of records using a user defined function in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to return the count of records using a user defined function in SQL? Below is the function I wrote but it fails.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f_GetRecordCount
(@year INT)
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN 
RETURN
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM dbo.employee
WHERE year = @year
END
```

Perhaps the SELECT query returns TABLE but I need to return INT.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning a table, it's one row containing the count.

If you need to return the value, you need to get that out of your query.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f_GetRecordCount(@year INT)
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @returnvalue INT;

    SELECT @returnvalue = COUNT(*) 
    FROM dbo.employee
    WHERE year = @year

    RETURN(@returnvalue);
END
```

To add a note of caution though, you should realise that this can have huge performance implications. If you use the UDF in a select-list or a condition, it will be called for every row in the result set - it probably won't be optimised out.

For example this query won't just call the function once, but once for every employee:

```
SELECT Id, f_GetRecordCount(2001)
FROM employee
```

Answer (score 0):

`RETURN` would need parentheses here so that it doesn't think it's just ending the function.

...but don't do it! Scalar functions are bad!